# Identity server 4 How to handler Login, Register and Logout functionality from client app

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am creating an application using .net core 3.1 with Identity server 4 OpenID connect with Razor Pages 
**Project Structure:**

- Api
- Auth Server (using identity server 4 template "dotnet new is4inmem")
- MvcClient (Razor pages)

**Startup.cs** (Auth server project)

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Environment = environment;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // configures IIS out-of-proc settings (see https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14882)
            services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
            {
                iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
                iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });

            // configures IIS in-proc settings
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(iis =>
            {
                iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
                iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
                .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);

            // in-memory, code config
            builder.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids);
            builder.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis);
            builder.AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);

            // or in-memory, json config
            //builder.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityResources"));
            //builder.AddInMemoryApiResources(Configuration.GetSection("ApiResources"));
            //builder.AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.GetSection("clients"));

            // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddAuthentication();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
    }
```

**Config.cs** (Auth server project)

```
    public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> Ids =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            };


        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
            new ApiResource[]
            {
                new ApiResource("Sample.Api", "My Sample Api #1")
            };


        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[]
            {
                // client credentials flow client
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "client",
                    ClientName = "Client Credentials Client",

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("511536EF-F270-4058-80CA-1C89C192F69A".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedScopes = { "Sample.Api" }
                },

                // MVC client using code flow + pkce
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mvc",
                    ClientName = "MVC Client",

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("49C1A7E1-0C79-4A89-A3D6-A37998FB86B0".Sha256()) },

                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/signin-oidc" },
                    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:5003/signout-oidc",
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/signout-callback-oidc" },

                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    RequireConsent= false,                    
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "Sample.Api" }
                },

                // SPA client using code flow + pkce
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "spa",
                    ClientName = "SPA Client",
                    ClientUri = "http://identityserver.io",

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,

                    RedirectUris =
                    {
                        "http://localhost:5002/index.html",
                        "http://localhost:5002/callback.html",
                        "http://localhost:5002/silent.html",
                        "http://localhost:5002/popup.html",
                    },

                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/index.html" },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:5002" },

                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "Sample.Api" }
                }
            };
    }
```

Startup.cs (From Mvc client)

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            }).AddCookie("cookie")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "cookie";
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClientId = "mvc";
                    options.ClientSecret = "49C1A7E1-0C79-4A89-A3D6-A37998FB86B0";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.ResponseType = "code";

                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("Sample.Api");
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                });

            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

**Privacy.cshtml.cs** (Razor page with Authorize attribute)

```
    [Authorize]
    public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<PrivacyModel> _logger;

        public PrivacyModel(ILogger<PrivacyModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
```

Everything is working fine I am able to login and access my Privacy authroize page but I have few questions here.

How can I get the logged in username and add logout button at the top of navbar ? (I want to add this on _layout.cshtml in Mvc client project not in Auth server _layout.cshtml).

Also that will be helpful if somebody can tell me how do I add Register functionality ? (same like above I want to add this Register button on the MVC client _layout.cshtml too).

I tried this as well but it is not working.
Here is the code from MVC project.

**/shared/_Layout.cshtml** (Mvc project)

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Sample.MvcClient</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>

                       @*How can I add logged in username, Register button and Logout button here*@

                    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name</a>
                        </li>                          
                    }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

**_Layout.cshtml (Auth Project)** - here I have commented the navbar because I want to display the user name and Logout and Register button on MVC client Layout not here.

```
 @*<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">*@
        <div class="container-fluid">
            @*<div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="~/">
                    <span class="navbar-brand">
                        <img src="~/icon.png" class="icon-banner">
                        IdentityServer4
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>*@

            @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@name <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="Account">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
    @*</div>*@

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

Can somebody help me out on this ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Work by example? [Scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) the Identity views and see how _LoginPartial works. It's as simple as adding `@User.Identity.Name` to the view for the username. It works because the User object is exposed by the HttpContext in your controllers and in your views.

Comment: @User.Identity.Name I  already using this but I don't get any value in this . I have used this in my /shared/Layout.cshtml.cs (mvc project).

Comment: Long time back I have used scaffolding but I remember at that time there was no API in my project and it worked for me but here the reason for using oidc is I am going to have 2 clients and thats why I added a centralized authentication approach. Can you explain a bit more on this.

Comment: @ShakshamSingh Did you get this working? I have the same requirement as you with the external auth service to authenticate Web client and API client.

Comment: Hey @ledragon No, not yet.